# OS X Extended Desktop Limits

Tags: macos, display

I am looking for information on whether there is a limit to the width/height of the OS X extended desktop.
I have seen setups with 2 rows of 3 displays, resulting in a 7680 x 2880 desktop.

Now I would like to connect six 1080p displays to a 2013 MacPro. 
I need the OS X desktop to span these in a single row for an effective resolution of 11520 by 1080 pixels.

Does anybody know, if this is possible?

Comment: What is it that you are doing ?

Comment: Out of curiosity what do you use to plug 6 monitors to your MacPro? Some [DVI/HDMI > USB adapter containing a DisplayLink chipset](http://superuser.com/a/689266/116475)? (I'm asking as I've had one complain that the driver for those chipsets were a bit slow with Yosemite)